# Making text fade in when hovered over and fade away forever when mouse is moved away?

Tags: jquery

Ok, so I'm not a coder, which I'm sure everyone hates to see on here. I just have to write an "electronic text" for an English class I'm taking. I'm pretty well-versed in HTML/CSS though, but not so much with Javascript/JQuery. I'm trying to make the HTML element "p" fade in if the mouse hovers over it, and fade out if mouse is not hovering over it, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Eventually, I would like each individual word to appear when hovered over and then disappear permanently (even if hovered over again) with the exception of a few words. If anyone wants to advise me on that, that would be fantastic. Is there a way to do that without making each word its own element? I'll be writing a whole story like that, so it would be really frustrating that way. Maybe some kind of for loop? Any way, thanks. My current code is below:

HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(

  function() {
    $("p").hover(
      function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("p").stop().fadeIn();
      },
      function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("p").stop.fadeOut();
      }
    );
  });
```

```css
* {}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
}

.story {
  float: left;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="story">
    <p>
      Everyone was a dead bug. It's not under there. Please don't look.
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: No, each word will have to be its own element, but it's pretty trivial to split on spaces and create the elements programatically. Use SO's code feature you make your example executable if you want more help.

Comment: Alright, I think it's executable now...(?) is it?

Comment: @jeepersmcface Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vz5d1yft/2/)? I can make this a more elaborate answer if it's on the right track.

Comment: `stop.fadeOut()` won't work if `stop().fadeIn()` does. I'm guessing that it's supposed to be `stop().fadeOut()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would do the trick. I've broken it out a bit for readability and explanation, but I'll include a more concise snippet as well.

**Concise (JS Only):**

```js
var exceptions = ["lorem", "ipsum", "consectetur", "pharetra"];

$("p").each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text().split(" ").map(function(x) {
    return exceptions.includes(x.toLowerCase()) ? x : "<span class='hover'>" + x + "</span>"
  }).join(" ");
  $(this).html(txt);
}).on("mouseover", ".hover", function() {
  $(this).addClass("hovering");
}).on("mouseout", ".hovering", function() {
  $(this).attr("class", "");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Full:**

```js
var exceptions = ["lorem", "ipsum", "consectetur", "pharetra"];

$("p").each(function() {           //for all paragraphs

    var txt = $(this).text()       //get text, split it up, add spans where necessary, put it back together
        .split(" ")
        .map(function(x) { return exceptions.includes(x.toLowerCase()) ? x : "<span class='hover'>" + x + "</span>"})
        .join(" ");
    $(this).html(txt);             //set the text to our newly manipulated text

}).on("mouseover", ".hover", function() {

    $(this).addClass("hovering");  //set opacity to 100%

}).on("mouseout", ".hovering", function() {

    $(this).attr("class", "");     //set opacity to 0%, remove "hover" events

})
```

```css
.hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.hovering {
    opacity: 1;
}

span {
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
}

p {
    cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

hover around in the area below...
<br>
<br>

<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In pharetra risus nec maximus rutrum. Vestibulum vulputate, elit ac euismod gravida, felis erat eleifend felis, vel blandit lorem ex sit amet est. Cras luctus bibendum dolor, vel consequat magna.
    Morbi pellentesque turpis metus. Pellentesque sit amet erat ex. Integer et nisi nisl. Quisque ornare mollis velit, id elementum elit pharetra at. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur
    cursus cursus dolor, eu laoreet mauris dapibus vitae. Nunc ac ipsum sit amet diam suscipit lobortis. Nam nec vehicula augue. Cras nec sapien vitae leo gravida vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
    Etiam viverra bibendum aliquet. Aenean erat ligula, commodo id aliquet vel, eleifend ac orci. Aliquam blandit libero feugiat augue tincidunt, id fringilla lectus aliquam. Nulla ut nisl sit amet nulla feugiat porta. Curabitur euismod, mi vitae luctus facilisis,
    est risus ornare erat, sed efficitur justo lorem nec urna. Cras in fringilla dolor. Aliquam faucibus scelerisque nunc, et rutrum quam pharetra ac. Vestibulum velit enim, consequat id nisi in, laoreet feugiat turpis. Phasellus auctor pharetra ultrices.
    In ut condimentum lectus. Integer at dui egestas, ultrices metus pulvinar, venenatis mi. Donec vitae mauris viverra, convallis urna sit amet, posuere sapien. Sed quis magna odio. Vivamus mauris ipsum, euismod non sagittis eu, pretium et neque. Nunc
    consequat ipsum eget magna facilisis mattis. Nulla eu lorem id tortor faucibus placerat.
</p>
```

I've broken the paragraph apart by words using `.split(" ")`, and then applied a `<span class="hover"></span>` to any that aren't in the list of exceptions using `.map()`. Then, we put it back together with spaces using `.join(" ")`.

Using CSS and some basic jQuery events, I add opacity on any hovered element, and then remove all classes when the mouse leaves - this sets its opacity to 0, and restricts it from "reactivating".

Comment: should this work if I just put this code into their respective file-types (CSS, HTML, JS) in a folder together? It seems to be having problems when I try to run it on my normal computer and not the code snippet engine thing.

Comment: How you implement it is up to you, but you'll need to wrap the jQuery in a page load event... before the javascript, put `$(document).ready(function() {` and after it put `})`. Make sure your include the CSS and JS files in the `<head>` of the HTML page.

Comment: I wrapped it in the page load event, and it still doesn't seem to be working. I included the file in the HTML head with `<script type = "text/javascript" src="NarrativeTheory.js"></script>` The file name is definitely "NarrativeTheory.js" and they are in the same folder. I added an alert in the Javascript to check to see whether it's working or not, and it doesn't seem to be. My javascript begins with `$document.ready(function() {

alert("Help!");`